# How to strip a Facebook page fans profile pictures?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, download, get, image

Is it possible to strip the profile pictures of fans of a page?

I'm trying to basically download all of my page's fans profile pictures. I know it's not possible to get a list of names but is this the same for profile pictures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible for the profile pictures too. You cannot get the fans personal data.